# WordPress Plugin is invisible

Tags: macos, wordpress, debian, mamp

I create a plugin, everythinks works fine in local. I use MAMP
But, on my server Debian, the plugin is invisible.
Then, I changed 
chmod -R 775 wp-content
But still doesn't works ?

Comment: How about pasting some code? This issue has nothing to do with folder permissions. Did you upload the plugin to the correct area?

Comment: I find the solution, I changes the woner and group. 
chown nobody:nogroup menu_css3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a lot to go on, maybe add a bit more info and/or some code. Do you mean you don't see it in your plugin list? Check these:

1. Did you upload in the correct map (inside wp-content/plugins)
2. Are you looking at the correct server/website?
3. Has the index.php or other file the required wordpress plugin comments?

what Wordpress version do you use?

Comment: I find the solution, I changes the woner and group. 
chown nobody:nogroup menu_css3

Comment: up, it's fixed, the answer has up.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:
Ensure there is a php file with the same name (+ .php) as the folder you placed your plugin in (beware debian is case sensitive about file names).

Comment: no, I fixed.
I changed everythinks to 775 and chown nobody:nogroup menu_css3.
And works, but I don't undestand, why I need to do that, when I push my project ?